# Adding non-selectable views in Gallery (like header and footer)

Tags: android, android-widget

I wish to add header and footer views to a Gallery, but I don't want them to be selectable, and I don't want the Gallery to automatically snap to them - instead, they should behave more like an overscroll area.

Any good way to do this?
Thanks